# Deserialize LocalDateTime from incoming JSON

Tags: json, spring, rest, date, localdate

I have created Spring Boot REST Api and I need handle with REST Controller object which contains LocalDateTime and LocalDate variables.

here is my sample object:

```
public class Foo {
   private LocalDateTime dateTime;
   private LocalDate date;

   // others variables, geeters and setters
}
```

and my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/foo")
public void fooApi(@RequestBody @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Foo foo) {
    // calling some service
}
```

I've tried solution above, and send that json:

```
{  
   "dateTime":"2018-02-05T11:59:11.332Z",
   "date":"2018-02-05T11:59:11.332Z"
   ...
}
```

[image]

As you can see I sending time 12:59 .. but controller hit with time 11:59.
Can you tell me how correct pass date and time to spring rest? I also have this in application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You are sending time with time-zone (Z) but `LocalDateTime` cannot store time-zone.

Comment: So in how format should I send it ?:/

Comment: It took me a while to figure out that `toISOString` is [a Javascript method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) (not Java).

Answer (score 3):

`LocalDateTime` does not hold any time-zone information. Assuming that you want time without timezone (*local* time) and receive the time for the client/user, you should send without timezone:

```json
{  
  "dateTime":"2018-02-05T12:59:11.332",
   ...
}
```

Note from your example, time part is changed to 12:59, and Z for UTC timezone is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct the description as in json you are passing 11:59 but you are saying you are passing 12:59.

As per the difference that you have mentioned, It is because of timezone.

d.toISOString is giving the date in UTC format. However, `d= new Date()` is giving the timezone(system timezone) specific date, in your case it is [CET](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet)(Central European Time) which is utc+01:00 means 1 hour ahead of utc time.

Comment: I pass same date in postman as you can see in picture, can you tell me what is correct form of sending date to make spring able detect timezone?

Comment: As I can see you want to pass only in utc timezone, right? If yes, Are you using jackson? Jackson by default sets the timezone for DateTime as GMT which is in most purpose  is identical to UTC. However, If you really want to specify the format as UTC use: `objectMapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`

Comment: I will implement javascript client later, so I do it by your advice ... for now I just tested my api in postman so I get current date from browser console as you can see on picture and send it to controller. So which format do you recommend? This object mapper is a bean?

Comment: Sorry, I am not a javascript expert. You should edit your question against and add javascript tag. By seeing rest and spring, I thought you api  is in java only, Isn't that the case?? I will recommend you to send date in UTC format only. What you can do is as the response of your api you can give timezone specific response. Just think of storing and receiving your data in timezone agnostic form and responding with timezone information to make client's life easy and storage also consistent. Also you should give display ready data from your api to your javascript client.

Comment: Also you should give display ready data from your api to your javascript client. i.e. format the date in whichever format you want and javascript client just display it as it is. Imagine you will build native apps for android and ios someday.You do not want to copy the conversion logic to all platform :)